# How do i save all the values from the checkbox and drop lists

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql

So i have this problem i have 6 columns with n check boxes in columns,

```
<ul>
        <li>
          <input type="checkbox" name="kuche[]"  id="check" value="freie Falächen reinigen / abstauben">
          <label for="check"></label>
          <p>freie Falächen reinigen / abstauben</p>
          <div class="rutina"></div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <input type="checkbox" name="kuche[]"  id="check" value="Griffspuren allg. entfernen"> <label for="check"></label><label for="check"></label>
          <p>Griffspuren allg. entfernen</p>
          <div class="rutina"></div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <input type="checkbox" name="kuche[]"  id="check" value="Türen vollflächig reinigen"> <label for="check"></label>
          <p>Türen vollflächig reinigen</p>
          <div class="rutina"></div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <input type="checkbox" name="kuche[]"  id="check" value="Lavabo reinigen /entkalken"> <label for="check"></label>
          <p>Lavabo reinigen /entkalken</p>
          <div class="rutina"></div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <input type="checkbox" name="kuche[]" id="check" value="Spinnweben entfernen"> <label for="check"></label>
          <p>Spinnweben entfernen</p>
          <div class="rutina"></div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <input type="checkbox" name="kuche[]"  id="check" value="nass aufnehmen"> <label for="check"></label>
          <p>nass aufnehmen</p>
          <div class="rutina"></div>
        </li>
      </ul>
```

so this is one of the columns or the list there are 6 these , and when i click each of the check boxes in the div.rutina it will appear the drop down list when the checkbox is checked, here is the link for the live view : [example](http://jsbin.com/gohupitudu/1/)

So the problem here is how do i get all the values of dropdown list for each checkbox in the each column when i submit the form.

Comment: you can do getElementsByTagName('kuche[]'). this will return u a list and u can get all the values here

Comment: @Sushil `getElementsByTagName('kuche[]')` would retrieve all `<kuche[]></kuche[]>` elements. What you're looking for is `document.getElementsByName("kuche[]");`

Comment: Oh sorry @IronFlare, I meant document.getElementsByName. thanks for correcting me.

Comment: Guys i can get the values from the checkboxes but i can't get the values for each drop down list that is added when checkbox is checked there is the problem ? check the link

Comment: link the checkboxes to the dropdown lists by using the same key - ie. `kuche[1]`/`dropdown[1]`. As only the checkboxes that are clicked are passed on form submit, you will have to define the keys (not `kuche[]`). Then on form submit, loop through each checkbox, getting the key, and use the key to get the dropdown value - `foreach($_POST['kuche'] as $key => $value) { $_POST['dropdown'][$key]; }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Sean wrote the solution would be more or less like that, but i forgot to add it in that time when i had this problem sorry, i would give the added inputs the name ex: dropdown[] and then for each checkbox selected i would have also a dropdown so with a foreach loop i could save all the elements,

```
foreach($_POST['checkbox'] as $key => $value) {
    //value would be here for checkbox
    $value;
    //the value for dropdown would be here 
    $drop = $_POST['dropdows'][$key];
```

More or less this would be the solution.